# VB.net BinaryWriter Problem

Tags: vb.net, binarywriter

In c# i could do it like:

send.Write((ushort)9);

"send" is an instance of BinaryWriter, how can i do it in vb.net ? I've tried it like:

send.Write((UShort)9)

but i get "UShort is a type and cannot be used as an expression"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closer translation would be:

```
send.Write(ctype(9, UShort))
```

Comment: send.Write((CUShort(9)))

Think i will do it this way, still thank you both!

Answer (score 2):

This will work on all versions of VB.NET:

```
send.Write(CType(9, System.UInt16))
```